# Collection empty when accessed from rendered event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection that I am subscribing to, but when I attempt to access it from my `onRendered` event it always returns as an empty array.  Below is the method I am using:

```
FlightCounts = new Mongo.Collection("flightCounts");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('flightCounts');
  Template.hello.rendered = function(){
    var counts = FlightCounts.find().fetch()
    console.log(counts)
  }

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    Meteor.publish('flightCounts', function(){
      return flightCounts.find();
    })
  });
}
```

Can anyone see why my collection would always be empty here?  Any suggestions on how to get it populated?

Comment: See the "Subscriptions Don't Block" section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying issue is that the publish function should reference Meteor's `Mongo.Collection` name, `FlightCounts`, and not the raw `db.collection` name `flightCounts`:

```
Meteor.publish('flightCounts', function(){
  return FlightCounts.find();
});
```

I also agree with the prior answer that your template should check to ensure the subscription is ready before logging the data, otherwise it may not have arrived yet:

```
Template.hello.onRendered(function(){
  this.autorun(() => {
    let ready = Template.instance().subscriptionsReady();
    if (!ready){ return; }
    let counts = FlightCounts.find().fetch();
    console.log(counts);
  });
});
```

(Note that the newer syntax for `Template.name.rendered` is `Template.name.onRendered()`.)

Comment: I noticed that counts gets logged a bunch of times with this code.  Is that expected?  I had kind of assumed it would only run when `ready` had been set to true?

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behavior because FlightCounts.find() is a reactive data source, so every time that cursor changes the autorun will be rerun, even after subscriptionsReady() has been marked as true. Also, if your template is being re-rendered the function will run again. Note that you can stop the autorun from rerunning more than once if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('flightCounts');
    Template.hello.rendered = function() {
        var template = this;
        template.autorun(function () {
             var counts = FlightCounts.find().fetch()
             console.log(counts)
        });
    }
 }
```

Your collection is not populated because, it is still getting data from server. So you should wrap your code inside an autorun, so that it will re-run whenever data is updated.

P.S: I am on mobile, so formatting may not be proper. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `subscriptions` of `FlowRouter` or `waitOn` of `IronRouter` to put the subscribe there

**Update** Surprisingly, `IronRouter` now has the `subscriptions` option as well